# HttpException - Maximum request length exceeded in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I am working on an uploader in ASP.NET MVC 3. I'm using the AJAX upload control (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). When I attempt to upload a large file via IE, everything works. However, when I attempt to upload a large file via Chrome, I get an exception on the server that says "Maximum length exceeded.". I added the following configuration setting thinking that it would solve it:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" />
```

That didn't solve it though. My action code looks like the following:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  string home = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "files");
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request["qqFile"]))
  {
    string filename = string.Empty;
    foreach (string file in Request.Files)
    {
      HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = (HttpPostedFileBase)(Request.Files[file]);
      if (postedFile.ContentLength == 0)
        continue;

      filename = Path.Combine(home, Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
      if (Directory.Exists(baseDirectory) == false)
        Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDirectory);
      postedFile.SaveAs(filename);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // MY PROBLEM IS IN HERE
    string filename = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, Request["qqFile"]);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[Request.InputStream.Length];
    Request.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, buffer);
  }

  return Json(new { success = true }, "text/html");
}
```

Why can't I upload larger files via Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting the maxAllowedContentLength

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
             <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="X" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```